# How to check # of times a string is present in each substring in a string?

Tags: java, nested-loops

So I'm currently working on a personal project and I made a program that tries to count the number of substrings that have a certain string

So this is how I called my method:

***countSubstringsStartingWith("Miss Mississippi", "si"))***

And I want the output to be:

```
11
```

So I wrote this method

```java
public static int countSubstringsStartingWith(String sentence, String target)  
    {       
      int count = 0;
         for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length()-1; i++){
            String subS = sentence.substring(0, i + 1);
            if(subS.substring(0,target.length() -1).equals(target)) {
               count++;
            }
         } 
      return count;
    }
```

But I get this output:

```
0
```

### Further Explanation:

So the input "Miss Mississippi" will break down to the following substrings:

```
M | Mi | Mis | Miss | Miss | Miss M | Miss Mi | Miss Mis | etc....
```

#### ***I want to check each substring for the target, and if there is the target present then it adds 1 to count***

Any idea how to solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of [`str.indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-):

```
class Main {
    public static int countSubstringsStartingWith(String sentence, String target) {
        int count = 0;
        int targetLength = target.length();
        int sentenceLength = sentence.length();
        if (targetLength > sentenceLength) {
            return count;
        }
        int index = sentence.indexOf(target);
        while (index >= 0) {
            count += sentenceLength - (index + targetLength - 1);
            index = sentence.indexOf(target, index + 1);
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(countSubstringsStartingWith("Miss Mississippi", "si"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
11
```

Comment: Amazing question! Could legit be an interview question at a big tech company!